# How does clojure.test store a test which is defined using deftest?

Tags: clojure

I was wondering what data structure Clojure uses to store a test which is defined using deftest.

I thought its a map and I expected to get it's class as PersistentArrayMap but it comes out like it's own class.

Does it use records for the test ?

```
user=> (use 'clojure.test)
nil
user=> (deftest test-test)
#'user/test-test
user=> (class test-test)
user$test_test
```

When we run the tests we only provide the namespace, how does it automatically identify all tests in the namespace and start running them one by one ?

Are these tests added to a some sort of list of tests every-time we create one using deftest in the current namespace?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you refer to the source code of [test.clj](https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/master/src/clj/clojure/test.clj) you can see that the deftest macro creates a var in the current namespace through the call to [vary-meta](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/vary-meta).

```
 (defmacro deftest
  [name & body]
   (when *load-tests*
    `(def ~(vary-meta name assoc :test `(fn [] ~@body))
      (fn [] (test-var (var ~name))))))
```

The test itself is inside that var.

Running a test is equivalent to checking all the var in the namespace that have a :test associated.

Removing some surrounding glue that gives:

```
 (doseq [v (vals (ns-interns ns))]
   (when (:test (meta v))
     (each-fixture-fn (fn [] (test-var v)))))
```

Comment: Thanks. I am still getting used to reading long clojure code. your explanation along with the necessary snippets are really helpful.